# Adjektiv zu "Lekt"

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

Ich bin auf ein Wort einer anderen Sprache (Afrikaans) gestoßen, und frage mich ob es ein deutsches Äquivalent dazu gibt. Die afrikaanse Entsprechung zu "[Lekt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lekt)" ist "*lek*", und es gibt auch ein Adjektiv dazu, *lekties*, das so beschrieben ist: "eigen an einer Sprachvarietät, die eine eigene Identität darstellt". Ich bin mir nicht sicher ob da "spracheigen(tümlich)" passt, es erscheint mir etwas weitgefasster? Wörter wie "soziolektisch/ideolektisch/etc." sind dann wiederum spezieller.

Comment: Wer das sehr obskure Wort "Lekt" akzeptiert, der akzeptiert sicherlich auch die normale Bildung "lektisch". Warum sollte es die nicht geben?

Comment: Das Wort "lektisch" wird im Bereich der Mathematik und Informatik schon wie das englische Wort "lectic" in der Bedeutung "Wörter/Buchstaben betreffend" als Gegensatz zu "numerisch" (Zahlen betreffend) verwendet. Man kann z.B. numerische und lektische Sortierung unterscheiden. Das ist aber nicht die Bedeutung, die hier in der Frage gesucht wird.

Comment: Ich finde *lektisch* auch durchaus akzeptabel. Darüberhinaus: In Zusammensetzungen wird bisweilen *-lektal* verwendet: *dialektale Ausdrucksweise*.

Comment: Polysemie ist etwas ganz Natürliches :-) Niemand hat Probleme mit Sätzen, die "Bank" verwenden, und wer mit Sprache arbeitet, hat auch keine Probleme mit Sätzen, die "lektisch" im Kontext verwenden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort *Lekt* in der beschriebenen Bedeutung ist eine Ableitung aus *Dialekt.* Da das dazugehörige Adjektiv *dialektal* lautet (und nicht *dialektisch,* was eine andere Bedeutung hat), ist die Form ***lektal*** zu empfehlen.

Die Form *lektisch* scheint hingegen für ein Fachwort in der Mathematik gebraucht zu werden.